# SwiftUI Let View disappear automatically

Tags: swiftui

I have a view that is triggered by a button touch. It appears nicely, all good. Now I want the View to disappear automatically again after a few seconds.

The view should disappear automatically without having to hit the button again.

Below my test project

```
import SwiftUI  

struct ContentView: View {  
  @State private var presentClipboardView = false  
  @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0  


  var body: some View {  
  VStack{  
  Button(action: {  
  let pasteboard = UIPasteboard()  
  pasteboard.string = "http://I_AM_A_URL.com"  

  withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {  
  self.presentClipboardView.toggle()  
  }  
  }, label: {  
  HStack {  
  Image(systemName: "list.dash")  
  .padding(.trailing)  
  VStack(alignment: .leading) {  
  Text("Open URL")  
  .font(.headline)  
  }  

  Spacer()  
  }  
  }  
  )  
  if(self.presentClipboardView){  
  LabelView()  
  }  
  }  

  }  
}  

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {  
  static var previews: some View {  
  ContentView()  
  }  
}  

struct LabelView: View {  
  var body: some View {  
  Text("URL copied to clipboard!")  
  .padding(10)  
  .font(.title)  
  .foregroundColor(.white)  
  .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.green).shadow(color: .gray, radius: 3))  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this on LabelView()

```
LabelView().onAppear {
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { timer in
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                                self.presentClipboardView.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Both answers work, accepting this one because it seems cleaner

Answer (score 2):

lets try

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var flag = false
    let time = 3.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if flag {
                DetailView(flag: $flag, showTime: time)
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.flag.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("show for \(time.description) seconds")
            }.disabled(flag)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var flag: Bool
    let showTime: Double
    var body: some View {
        Text("Welcome").font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(Color.orange)
            .onAppear {
                let _delay = RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType(.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: self.showTime))
                RunLoop.main.schedule(after: _delay) {
                    self.flag.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]